# How to make a map in swift and how to make an icon where your location bubble is?

Tags: swift, dictionary, apple-maps

I'm really new to swift and I'm not sure how to make a map. The apple developer support articles aren't really helping. But I want a map that shows your location and an icon (a phone SF Symbol) where your location bubble/ pin is.

I tried to use the map(coordinate: region) and that is depricated so it doesn't work without the deprication warning, and I haven't figured out any other way to do it. And i tried MapMarker and it is also depricated. And MapMarker also doesn't show a custom icon.

Comment: https://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/create-mkmapview-in-swift-programmatically/

Comment: Download the "Developer" app and search for "Map" you'll find some WWDC videos with all the information you need.